# Performing of my basic query taking long time

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, ssms, ssms-2014

I use MsSQL. I have a "jobs" table which has 140 columns and includes more than 4 million records in it. This table's columns mostly varchar and bit.

The table's 40 columns connected to some other tables. Like "issuerid" from "issuers" table, "fileid" from "files"...

The indexes of table is only on the "fileid" which is non-unique and non-clustered.

My basic query is like in the following:

```
 select issuerid,count(id) as total , sum(case when X_Status=1 then 1 else 0 end) P_Count  
from jobs  where 1=1  and issuerid='1001' and  creationdate between '01/01/2019 12:00:01 AM' and '06/30/2019 11:59:59 PM' group by issuerid
```

The duration of the query is: 1min 20seconds (The PC has SSD and 4GB Ram)

So i tried to index on issuerid but it didn't affect as much.

I have a lot of queries on this table for my asp page. For example the sum case changes mostly;
`sum(case when Y_Status=1 then 1 else 0 end) P_Count` 
Like this.

So even tried to let 2 columns in the table and executed this query 
`select count(id) as, sum(case when X_Status=1 then 1 else 0 end) P_Count from newjobs where 1=1` 
and this took around 30seconds.

I read many topics and article to improve query performance but didn't work. Is there anyone who has any idea to share?

Thank you.

Comment: What indexes do you have applied to id, X_Status, and creation date? also is issuerid='1001' is this numeric? it would be better if it were an int then you could filter on an int which would be quicker. allof the columns I have mentioned would benefit from an index

Comment: Include the table and it's indexes DDL, and the query execution plan would be great. Use https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/.

Comment: @jimmy8ball Firstly the Id already the primary key and I had on fileid. I tried to index all separately on to creationdate, issuerid and X_Status. But didn't affect. I run the query without creationdate criteria but still takes long time.
The issuerid is "bigint"
Thank you for your interest.

Comment: What about your issuerid is this an int?

Comment: if you isserid is an int then dont use single quotes, it'll be faster with simply issuerid=1001. Using single quotes forces it to be treated at text

Comment: @EzLo the table has 140 columns that's why i didn't add it. So should i? thank you

Comment: @jimmy8ball this is a good advice thank you. But the thing is why this query  -> select count(id) as total, sum(case when X_Status=1 then 1 else 0 end) P_Count from jobs where 1=1 <-  works so slow?

Comment: @Maestro00 looks like you have a valid response, you simply need more effective indexing

Comment: @jimmy8ball While I agree that there is no need for the single quotes around an int, and they should not be there as it makes it less clear what the data type of issuerID is, as long as the actual column is an int, this doesn't actually affect how the query runs, only how it is compiled, and the speed difference will be negligible. The compiler needs to do a one time implicit conversion from varchar to int. This should take microseconds, and not be consequential for the execution.

Comment: Yes @jimmy8ball exactly it is. Thank you so much.

Comment: @GarethD great point - thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following should work for your exact query:

```
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX IX_Jobs__IssuerID_CreationDate ON dbo.Jobs (IssuerID, CreationDate)
    INCLUDE (X_Status);
```

Since your query filters on IssuerID and CreationDate these are the key columns, then I hav eadded X_Status as a non key column so that the whole query can be run from this index and there is no chance of a bookmark lookup or an index scan.

As an aside, your current where clause will always exclude things that happen in the first second of the first day and the last second of the last day (i.e between `00:00:00` and `00:00:01`on 1st January, and `06/30/2019 23:59:59` and `07/01/2019 00:00:00`). This may be deliberate, but I suspect it isn't. It is usually much better, and also more clear as to your intentions to use an open ended date range.

```
WHERE   CreationDate > '20190101'
AND     CreationDate < '20190701'
```

Or More likely:

```
WHERE   CreationDate >= '20190101'
AND     CreationDate < '20190701'
```

I have also swtiched to a culture invariant date time format, so that the date literal is interpretted as the same date on every machine. For more reading see:

- [What do BETWEEN and the devil have in common?](https://sqlblog.org/2011/10/19/what-do-between-and-the-devil-have-in-common)
- [Bad habits to kick : mis-handling date / range queries](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/16/bad-habits-to-kick-mis-handling-date-range-queries)

Comment: This is a great and very instructive answer. I am very thankful to you Gareth. I have one last question. As i told you, i have a lot of status columns which represent another things. So you think creating different indexes base on this status like you've done, is a good way for me ? Or creating 5-6indexes like this has a negative impact?

Comment: Every additional nonclustered index comes with a performance cost during write operations, so it is always a balancing act between determining if the benefits gained during read operations outweighs this cost. I cannot answer this as I don't know how often you will be running queries that read from this index and how often you will be adding/updating records in the table.

Comment: Ok let me give you short information about adding periods of the table. I get 1.5million records in 6months period but this may increase base on the client actions. So i perform different kind of queries on this table, it's like a main table for me as you can understand from the columns count. I run the query which you helped me generally once a month. Thank you again.